# How to get more useful error messages?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

React + ES6 Babel spits the following error message whenever I try to access `undefined` (ex. trying `person.age` where `person === undefined`.)

[image]

This also happens when I mistype an `import` statement or make a mistake when I destructure a `props` object. For example, I could make the following mistake:

```
const { name, age } = this.props.person
// but `this.props.person` only has a `name` property.
```

Such lack of error messages is a pain. Is there some option that I missed to set? How is everyone coping with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a highly requested feature and probably is going to be implemented in next React version. For now you can use [redbox-react](https://github.com/KeywordBrain/redbox-react). As far as I know [react-transform-catch-errors](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-catch-errors) is deprecated.

```
/* global __DEV__ */
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'

const root = document.getElementById('root')

if (__DEV__) {
  const RedBox = require('redbox-react').default
  try {
    render(<App />, root)
  } catch (e) {
    render(<RedBox error={e} />, root)
  }
} else {
  render(<App />, root)
}
```

Comment: It seems that `react-redbox` and `react-transform-catch-errors` are all deprecated in favor of `react-hot-loader`, but I still get the unfriendly errors after applying `react-hot-loader`

Comment: redbox-react works perfectly for me. Try to add `output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate = '/[resource-path]'` to webpack config - https://github.com/KeywordBrain/redbox-react#sourcemaps-with-webpack

Comment: Any updates to this? The next version of React is already out... are there any hooks that make this easy/better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is annoying. One way that helps, is to wrap the render-method of every React-component with try / catch, so you can see the actual error and not the gibberish provided by React. Add this to your babel.js-config, so it's automatically done: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-catch-errors.